# Game loop implementation using Java Swing and Multithreading concerns

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, game-loop

I wrote a basic Engine class for a Java 2d game but I'm not sure about multithreading problems though it works good. I decided to run game loop in another thread to avoid the repaint() method of Swing to never being called.

```
/**
 * Engine class.
 */
public class Engine {

    private static final long PERIOD = 20;
    private MainWindow window;
    private World world;
    private Thread game;
    private boolean pause;

    public Engine() {
        window = new MainWindow(Engine.this);
    }

    public void startGame() {
        this.world = new World(this);
        this.resumeGame();
        this.game = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameLoop();
            }
        });
        this.game.start();
    }

    public MainWindow getWindow() {
        return this.window;
    }

    public void gameLoop() {
        long prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(!world.isGameOver()) {
            long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long dt = currTime - prevTime;
            if (!this.pause) {
                this.world.update(dt);
                this.window.render();
            }
            this.waitForNextFrame(currTime);
            prevTime = currTime;
        }
        this.window.changePanel(new ResultScreen(this, world.getResult()));
    }

    private void waitForNextFrame(long startTime) {
        long dt = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (dt < PERIOD) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(PERIOD - dt);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopGame() {
        this.pause = true;
        this.window.changePanel(new PauseExampleScreen(this));
    }

    public void resumeGame() {
        this.window.changePanel(this.world.getScene());
        /*
         * input is set after the scene is made visible
         */
        this.world.getScene().setInput(this.world.getInput());
        this.pause = false;
    }

}
```

```
/**
 * Launches the game.
 */
public class Launch {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Engine();
    }
}
```

Could someone explain how the threads works here and if it's fairly safe to use it like this?

Comment: *"and if it's fairly safe to use it like this?"* - the basic answer is, it's not. Swing is not thread safe and you shouldn't update the UI, or any state the UI relies on, from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. Swing also makes use of a passive rendering engine, this is something which you don't control. You can request paint passes, but it's up to the `RepaintManager` to decide what and when it should occur.  As a "general" recommendation, if you want to do this kind of think in Swing, you're better of using a Swing `Timer` as the "clock"

Comment: If you want "control" over the paint process, then you should be looking at using a [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html).  This will give you "as close to the metal" control over the painting process and you can do so from a seperate thread of your own creating.  I would also recommend having a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) for a bit more detail about how the painting system in Swing works

Comment: Having said all that, if you're interesting in this kind of thing, you might be better of using JavaFX, which was really made for this kind of thing

Comment: [mcve] please ..